# How can I prove ganache is safe at room temperature?

Tags: food-safety, storage-method, food-science, ganache

Ganache I make is a ratio of 2:1, cream is boiled 3 times to reduce water content, chocolate is a mixture of dark and milk. Upto 50g of glucose syrup is added as a preservative.

I know the ganache is perfectly fine to eat for upto 10 days at room temperature. (Very experienced in this test lol).

How can I prove (without paying for scientific analysis) that it's good for a suggested shelf life of 5 days at room temperature in uk. Or that there is enough sugar to preserve the emulsion?

Comment: To whom do you need to prove this? A government agency? A skeptical friend?

Answer (score 1):

A line of approach:

You could prove it by finding the actual water content of the Ganache vs. the sugar content.

The cream is cooked down somewhat similar to what happens when you do Dulce de Leche; and is turned to syrup.

High sugar products (candies, candied fruits) are relatively stable at room temperature (between 15c and 22c, according to wikipedia) because their water content is low which prevent microbial spoilage.